# Adding items to a nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, for-loop

I am trying to read a list within a list and add keys and values to a dictionary within a dictionary. But I get the 'str' object doesn't support assignment error.

Code:

```
report_dict = dict()
axis_list = []
results = self.report_data(conn)
for row in results:
  try:
    report_dict[row[0]] = row[3]
    report_dict[row[0]][row[3]] = row[1]
  except IndexError:
    None 
  print(report_dict)
```

Result:

```
report_dict = { abc: {qwe:asd}, …..}
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of what `results` looks like?

Comment: @Wondercricket done.

Comment: @qwerty I think @Wondercricket meant the `results` variable in your code, not the desired result of your code.

Comment: Its just a list within  a list. So essentially `row` is a list from which I am inputting abc, qwe,asd into the dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is make a nested dictionary. If I understand your input correctly, your code could be fixed just by setting `report_dict[row[0]]` to an empty dict, by changing

```
report_dict[row[0]] = row[3]
```

to

```
report_dict[row[0]] = {}
```

This would make the next line,

```
report_dict[row[0]][row[3]] = row[1]
```

add the key `row[3]` with value `row[1]` to the dictionary `report_dict[row[0]]`. This would give us:

```
report_dict = {row[0]: {row[3]: row[1]}, ...}
```

which I think is your expected output.

Comment: `report_dict[row[0]] = {}` in the for loop, wont it cause the data to be overwritten if the first key is same? Check the expected result.

Comment: @qwerty yes, you can't have duplicate keys in a dictionary. Please ask your new requirements in a new question rather than editing this answered question!

Comment: Okay, what would you do for duplicated keys, append it to another dictionary?

Comment: @qwerty depends what you want your data structure to be?

Comment: end of the day it should be a dictionary.